# SQL Server 2012: SSIS server registered in SSMS not showing status; still pops up "connect to server" dialog

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm having an odd issue I can't resolve.

This is a Win2008R2Ent server with SQL2012Ent with only SSAS and SSIS services installed.

**Problem:**

I have the SSIS server registered in my SSMS however:

1. There is not green arrow status icon beside the server icon in the Registered Servers list.
2. Double clicking the server does not automatically log me in. It still presents the "Connect to Server" dialog box.

I'm able to connect remotely just fine, except for the annoying dialog box which pops up (i just have to click connect). It does not pop up for any other server. After I log in, i see the green indicator light but only in the Object Explorer

Locally on the sever, I'm able to connect if i run SSMS as admin. I'm a domain admin and belong to the server's local administrator's group. Also no green arrow on the icon in the Registered Server list.

**Thoughts:**

1. I'm not sure the green arrow status light is supposed to be in the registered list, but i'm assuming so because all other servers have it.
2. This extra dialog box that pops up is very unusual and unnecessary as the server is already registered. I know it may sound like a tiny problem, but I want to be thorough and make sure i didn't miss anything. Unusual activity like this is a flag for me. My SQL admin friend also said that was unusual.

I'm wondering if any of this is normal behavior and hoping someone can share their experience in such a setup. I tried searching for these issues but didn't have much luck.

**Screenshot:**

[image: SSMS on my workstation showing registered server missing green arrow as well as the pop up dialog box when double clicking the server in the registered list]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying SP1 to your client to update the management tools? I found quite a few issues like this with the RTM tools.